# scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString need an implicit CanBuildFrom to fulfill documented features?

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, scala-collections

WrappedString Scaladoc 2.8.1:

"This class serves as a wrapper augmenting Strings with all the operations found in indexed sequences.
The difference between this class and StringOps is that calling transformer methods such as filter and **map will yield an object of type WrappedString** rather than a String"

```
  scala> import scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString
  import scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString

  scala> val s = new WrappedString("foo")               
  s: scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString = WrappedString(f, o, o)

  scala> s.filter(x => true)
  res1: scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString = WrappedString(f, o, o)

  scala> s.map(x => x)                                  
  res2: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Char] = Vector(f, o, o)
```

Alas, map returns a Vector and not a WrappedString. If I understand this correctly:

Filter works since it simply uses the newBuilder method, but map needs an implicit CanBuildFrom for WrappedString just like BitSet has. Is this a bug in code or documentation or am I missing something?

Also, the scaladoc simplified version doesn't make any sense to me:

```
def map [B] (f: (Char) ⇒ B) : WrappedString[B]
def map [B, That] (f: (Char) ⇒ B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[WrappedString, B, That]) : That
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
def map [B] (f: (Char) ⇒ Char) : WrappedString
def map [B, That] (f: (Char) ⇒ B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[WrappedString, B, That]) : That
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first would be a bug, one that shall be fixed for 2.9.

Comment: Do you mean it's a known bug? I couldn't find anything in https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac but I wanted to check here before I reported anything…?

Comment: I don't think there was a ticket about that, it's probably a good idea to report that.

Comment: Thanks, I opened a ticket over here: https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/4232